# How to transclude anything

Tags: angularjs, transclusion

I am transcluding an SVG element into another SVG directive. Here is the template for the parent directive called "component":

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

   <rect class="component-rect" width="{{rectWidth}}" height="{{rectHeight}}"></rect>

   <g ng-transclude></g>

</svg>
```

and here is the markup where the directive is used:

```
<g>
    <component ng-repeat="(id, component) in placedComponents">
        <text>{{component.label}}</text>
    </component>
</g>
```

I want to resize the `<rect>` in the template according to measured size of the transcluded `<text>` element. How can I get a reference to the transcluded `<text>` element in order to measure it and set the appropriate `rectWidth` and `rectHeight`?

Comment: Could you just use `element.find('text')` in the link function?

Comment: I want to be able to transclude anything, not just text. Maybe I should wrap the transclude with a ```<g>``` and use ```find('g')```?

Comment: Then you just want to get the transclued content, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the `ng-transclude` in the template, and do the trascultion yourself in the link function like this:

```
.directive('component', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'component.html',
    transclude: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls, transcludeFn) {
      scope.rectHeight = 100;
      scope.rectWidth = 100;

      transcludeFn(function (clones) {
        // clones are the transcluded elements
        element.find('g').append(clones);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

**Example plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/Zv9Q6AuNGfzeN2gs7q2f?p=preview

Hope this helps.